# Why is $N(x)=\pm1$ in this problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I encountered a proof but there is one step in the proof that I don't really understand.

To summarise I just write some portions of the proof:
In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, define a function $N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\to\mathbb{Z}$ by $N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2$. Notice that N is simply the square of the magnitude of the complex number $a+b\sqrt{-5}$. It follows that $N$ is multiplicative: $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$. If $x$ is a unit, then $N(x)=\pm1$, since it must divide $1$. It follows that $1$ and $-1$ are the only units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

My question is:
Why is $N(x)=\pm1$? If N is the square of the magnitude of the complex number x, then $N(x)$ should only be $1$, why is there the $-1$? Isn't the square of the magnitude always positive?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the statement isn't incorrect, it's just not the strongest statement you could make. The point is that if $xy = 1$ then $N(x) N(y) = N(1) = 1$, so $N(x)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, and the only such units are $\pm 1$. It happens that in this case you can rule out $-1$, but in other more general cases you won't be able to.

Answer (score 1):

The function $N$ you're considering takes on only nonnegative values, so the equality $N(x)=-1$ is impossible. However, the function can be defined on any quadratic extension such as $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and, in this case,
$$
N(a+b\sqrt{2})=a^2-2b^2
$$
which can indeed assume negative values. In fact $1+\sqrt{2}$ *is* invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Note that this function $N$ on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is multiplicative as well.